# Windows software for blocking specific website for a specific program (other than web browser)

Tags: youtube, parental-control, website-blocker, microsoft-onenote

I would like to ask for recommendations for a Windows software that can restrict a specific program from accessing a specific website, such as YouTube, while allowing other programs to access it. Modifying the hosts file is not an option as it would block the website for the entire computer.

I have tried using Cold Turkey to block YouTube, but this method only works in supported web browsers. Unfortunately, when I paste a YouTube video link into Microsoft OneNote, I can bypass the blocking rule and watch the video.

I am seeking a solution that can effectively block YouTube or any website for a specific program in Windows without blocking it for other programs.